# AngularJs Multiple Class in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to use multiple class in ng-class.These classes comes from my directive.

I need something like this;

```
ng-class="item.test1 item.test2"
```

**test1** and **test2** are my css classes.

When i call like this ,it does not work.

How can i call multiple class using ng-class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use array notation for multiple classes:

```
<my-element ng-class="[item.test1, item.test2]">Classes applied</my-element>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zgaj17hL/1/)

Comment: by the way if the classes are test1 & test2,one needs to remove the "item.", which I don't understand anyway

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use `class` for that purpose:

```
 <div class="{{item.test1}} {{item.test2}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this, it's a conditional:

```
<my-elem ng-class="{'class1':var==value1','class2':var=='value2'}">
```

but really, that's all in the official [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) you could have search for it.

Comment: The question wasn't about conditional, just to apply multiple classes